# Pandoc Lua filter to wrap chapters and sections in divs

Tags: lua, abstract-syntax-tree, pandoc

I have been using using javascript to wrap the chapter or section "contents" (the elements between it and the next chapter or section header) in a `div` (for UI purposes). I'd like to use a Lua filter to do the same thing at build-time instead of runtime.

From my reading of the abstract syntax tree ([AST](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.22/docs/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html)), these groups of elements aren't directly selectable in an obvious way. This leads me to believe I'll have to loop through all document elements, similar to how it's done in the following example from [the manual](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#creating-a-handout-from-a-paper).

```lua
function Pandoc(doc)
    local hblocks = {}
    for i,el in pairs(doc.blocks) do
        if (el.t == "Div" and el.classes[1] == "handout") or
           (el.t == "BlockQuote") or
           (el.t == "OrderedList" and el.style == "Example") or
           (el.t == "Para" and #el.c == 1 and el.c[1].t == "Image") or
           (el.t == "Header") then
           table.insert(hblocks, el)
        end
    end
    return pandoc.Pandoc(hblocks, doc.meta)
end
```

I think I could use a similar approach but accumulate elements between `Header` blocks and bundle them into `Div`s. Is this a reasonable approach or is there something obvious I'm missing here about the AST?

Comment: Maybe you don't need a filter. Does `--section-divs` work for your use-case?

Comment: @tarleb thanks -- it works but breaks something else ... tocbot, which I'm using for navigation. It needs the `id` to be in the header tag.